# Spring MockMvc WebApplicationContext is null when running JUnit Tests with Maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, spring-mvc, junit

I have a Spring mock-mvc JUnit test class that contains two tests. When I run the tests within Eclipse IDE **both tests pass** (I use Eclipse Maven plugin).

When running the tests from the command line using

```
mvn test
```

one of the tests fails because the  WebApplicationContext that is @Autowired is **sometimes** null.

Here is my test class

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({ "dev", "test" })
public class AddLinkEndpointMvcTest extends BaseMvc {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("WAC = " + wac);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void addLinkDoesNotSupportGet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/myurl")).andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
    }

    @Test
    public void addLinkBadRequestNoLinkAddress() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/myurl")).andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST));
    }
}
```

Here is the BaseMvc class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BaseMvc {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.a", "com.example.b" })
    @Profile("test")
    public static class TestConfig {

        static {
            System.out.println("TEST CONFIG");
        }

        // ...some beans defined here

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
            configurer.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("sample-webapp.properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("sample-domain.properties") });
            return configurer;
        }

    }

}
```

I have added the println calls to aide debugging. When running mvn test here is the relevant console output:

```
WAC = null
WAC = org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@38795184: startup date [Thu Sep 19 16:24:22 BST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

and the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.<init>(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:66)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:46)
        at com.mypackage.AddLinkEndpointMvcTest.before(AddLinkEndpointMvcTest.java:31)
```

So this is the problem line in the test

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;
```

Sometimes wac is null or has not completed initialisation before the JUnit @Before kicks in.

What I don't understand is the WebApplicationContext is sometimes null and why it passes in Eclipse IDE!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error. Are you sure that's the class involved?

Comment: Have you tried using constructor injection instead of field injection? This should force your `WebApplicationContext` to be initialized before `AddLinkEndpointMvcTest` is used.

Comment: @Sotiros Yes tried again today after a while and still same issue

Comment: Could you try `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` runner?

Answer (score 3):

you should add `@SpringBootTest` as an annotation before your test class.
Like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using getBean instead of auto wiring. This should assure that `WebApplicationContext` is initialized when you access it.

Example:

```
MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
```

Comment: JUnit needs a default constructor so wont let me get away with that

Answer (score -3):

Please use @WebAppConfiguration annotation. Your question is already answered here : [WebApplicationContext doesn't autowire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135492/webapplicationcontext-doesnt-autowire/30938195#30938195)

Comment: the annotation is present in the question